# Disabling dates in DatePicker without enabling previously disabled dates

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, javafx-datepicker

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Example extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox container = new VBox();
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        disableSomeDates(datePicker);
        
        Button disableMondaysButton = new Button("No Mondays!");
        disableMondaysButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                disableSomeMoreDates(datePicker);
            }
        });
        
        container.getChildren().add(datePicker);
        container.getChildren().add(disableMondaysButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(container);

        stage.setScene(scene); 
        stage.sizeToScene(); 
        stage.show(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
    
    public void disableSomeDates(DatePicker datePicker) {
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(param -> new DateCell() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                //Disables dates before current date
                setDisable(empty || date.compareTo(LocalDate.now()) < 0 );
            }
        }); 
    }
    
    public void disableSomeMoreDates(DatePicker datePicker) {
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(param -> new DateCell() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                //Disables mondays
                setDisable(empty || date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

In this example code I create a DatePicker and disable some dates (dates before today). Then by pressing the button it should disable Mondays and thus we should have all dates before today and all mondays disabled. In this case we'll end up with only mondays disabled.

How do I make it so that the button disables mondays without re-enabling dates before today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a single cell factory, generating cells which observe properties that can then be changed.

E.g.:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        BooleanProperty mondaysDisabled = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        
        VBox container = new VBox();
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(dp -> new DateCell() {
            
            {
                mondaysDisabled.addListener((obs, mondaysWereDisabled, mondaysAreNowDisabled) 
                    -> updateDisabledStatus());
            }
            
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                updateDisabledStatus();
            }
            
            private void updateDisabledStatus() {
                if (isEmpty()) {
                    setDisable(true);
                } else {
                    LocalDate date = getItem();
                    if (date.isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
                        setDisable(true);
                    } else {
                        if (mondaysDisabled.get() && date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY) {
                            setDisable(true);
                        } else {
                            setDisable(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        Button disableMondaysButton = new Button("No Mondays!");
        disableMondaysButton.setOnAction(event -> mondaysDisabled.set(true));
        
        container.getChildren().add(datePicker);
        container.getChildren().add(disableMondaysButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(container);

        stage.setScene(scene); 
        stage.sizeToScene(); 
        stage.show(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
    

}
```

---

For something of a more modular approach, you could keep an observable list of filters to check. E.g.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        ObservableList<Predicate<LocalDate>> dayFilters = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        dayFilters.add(date -> date != null);
        dayFilters.add(date -> ! date.isBefore(LocalDate.now()));
        
        VBox container = new VBox();
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(dp -> new DateCell() {
            
            {
                dayFilters.addListener((Change<? extends Predicate<LocalDate>> change) -> updateDisabledStatus());
            }
            
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                updateDisabledStatus();
            }
            
            private void updateDisabledStatus() {
                setDisable(false);
                for (Predicate<LocalDate> check : dayFilters) {
                    if (! check.test(getItem())) {
                        setDisable(true);
                        break ;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        Button disableMondaysButton = new Button("No Mondays!");
        disableMondaysButton.setOnAction(event -> dayFilters.add(date -> date.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        
        container.getChildren().add(datePicker);
        container.getChildren().add(disableMondaysButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(container);

        stage.setScene(scene); 
        stage.sizeToScene(); 
        stage.show(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
    

}
```